# Confused on the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and HashMap behavior in this example

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to understand how ConcurrentHashMap works. I found an example, but I'm not able to understand it. Here's its code:

```
Map<String, Object> myData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myData.put("A", 1);
myData.put("B", 2);
for (String key : myData.keySet()) {
    myData.remove(key);
}
```

This will throw an exception `ConcurrentModificationException` at runtime.

However, this code using `ConcurrentHashMap` will work correctly:

```
Map<String, Object> myData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
myData.put("A", 1);
myData.put("B", 2);
for (String key : myData.keySet()) }
    myData.remove(key);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why ConcurrentHashMap allows to remove keys while the HashMap throws an exception? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just one of the features of `ConcurrentHashMap`.  To quote from the docs:

> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements
>   reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the
>   creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

`ConcurrentHashMap` does not really do this to support your use case, however.  It's done to allow iteration in one thread happen concurrently with modifications made in other threads.

If this is your only reason for using `ConcurrentHashMap`, then you should probably reconsider, because it is a lot more expensive than `HashMap`.  You are better off just making a copy of the key set before using it like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myData.put("A", 1);
myData.put("B", 2);
for(String key: myData.keySet().toArray(new String[0]))
    myData.remove(key);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `Iterator.remove()` instead of making a copy of the whole key set?  (Or clearing the map?)

Comment: @LouisWasserman  I'm assuming that `myData.remove(key)` is a placeholder for some more complicated operation that might remove entries.  Of course if that can be routed to `iterator.remove()` then that works fine.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you , if I understand in ConcurrentHashMap example with each iteration we remove a key there also an update keySet but in the HashMap there no update for keySet  until the end of the loop that's why there's an exception

Comment: @E2rabi the keySet is updated immediately in both cases, but in a HashMap that update can ruin the iterator that the loop is using, so the iterator will throw an exception the next time you use it.  In the ConcurrentHashSet the update does not affect the iterator at all.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  Not quite.  The iterator is _weakly consistent,_ meaning it "may (but [is] not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's true, but there isn't practically that much leeway in this *single-threaded* use case.  The doc says that the iteration "reflects the state of the hash table at some point...", i.e., that the whole iteration must be consistent with the whole state of the hash table at some point in time.  Once you've seen an element in the iteration, it may end up getting deleted at any point *during* the iteration, which makes consistency with any "point in time" *after* that deletion a lot more difficult  - impossible if we only delete elements that we've already seen, as the OP does